# Returning the digit count of a number using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to return the count of digits in a number using recursion like this:
DigitCount(3456) → 4.
The code that I have without using recursion works fine, which is:

```
    def DigitCount(n)
        return len(str(n))
```

But when I try using recursion in this way:

```
    def DigitCount(n):
        return len(str(DigitCount(n)))
```

I get an error message saying 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'

Comment: this is an infinite loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your recursive function is that you didn't specify a base case to end the recursion, producing an infinite loop that ends with a stack overflow.

When writing recursive procedures, you have to think how to make the problem *smaller* at each call (in this case, dividing by `10` does the trick) until you reach a point where the problem is so simple, that you already know the answer - for instance, a number less than `10` has a single digit. Try this:

```
def DigitCount(n):
    if n < 10:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + DigitCount(n / 10) # use n // 10 in Python 3.x
```

It works as expected, as long as `n` is greater than or equal to zero:

```
DigitCount(0)
=> 1
DigitCount(234)
=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
def DigitCount(n):
    if n<10: return 1
    return 1 + DigitCount(n//10)
```

The idea is:

- a number smaller than 10 has length 1
- a number greater than 10 has length 1 + length(n//10); for instance 456 has length 1 + length(45).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using strings also.

```
def digitCount(n):
    if len(str(n)) == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + digitCount(str(n)[1:])
```

It's a bit dirty, and very inefficient but works.